# Required field not working when working via Rest

Tags: activiti

I have created a simple model with 2 form properties variables.

The model has a start point, to the start i connected a user task, and connected the user task to end point.
 in the user task i added 2 form properties and set them with "required" attribute:

```
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:formProperty id="SomeID" name="Some ID" type="string" required="true"></activiti:formProperty>
    <activiti:formProperty id="SomeName" name="Some Name" type="string" required="true"></activiti:formProperty>
  </extensionElements>
```

I am sending http message to the Rest API (via C#) to complete the task.

When i send the request with no variables in json body -> only complete as "action" it is ok (get a response) and the task is removed, how could it be ? shouldnt i get error message that the required variables are not in the json body?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that only the "Form" API takes the Form Property required/writable flags into consideration.

I imagine you are using the following API:

POST http://localhost:8080/brazos-open/service/runtime/tasks/22557

{
  "action" : "complete",
  "variables" : []
}

This will give you the behavior you are experiencing.

However, if you use the Form API as follows:

POST http://localhost:8080/brazos-open/service/form/form-data

{
  "taskId" : "22557",
  "properties" : [
    {
      "id" : "numberOfDays",
      "value" : 2
    }
  ]
}

You will get an error indicating the the missing field (startDate in this case) is required.

Keep in mind, the out of box Form implementation, even in the latest version of Activiti is very rudimentary. There are much better options available.

Hope this helps,
Greg