# Required input field - REST API fetching it causing issues

Tags: flutter, rest, dart

On my website I have an `input field` with a `required` attribute. Using Flutter / Dart.

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
       minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
```

Now, I am trying to fetch that field like so:

```
content = json["content"]["rendered"];
```

Problem is that it is not showing anymore. If I remove the required attribute from my input field, it is showing again.

What is going wrong here? Anyone?

I found this, but this also did not work for me:
[Required field not working when working via Rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130109/required-field-not-working-when-working-via-rest)

Comment: share your code as well or explain your question in detail

Comment: What code? It's just an input field with required attribute? Like so: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
       minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">